# Struct.new on a class definition

Tags: ruby

I came across [some interesting Ruby code](http://zadasnotes.blogspot.ch/2011/03/rails-tips-using-delayedjob-to-schedule.html) today.

```
class MeetingReminderJob < Struct.new(:user, :meeting)
  def perform
    send_reminder(user, meeting)
  end
end
```

What is the purpose of the `< Struct.new(:user, :meeting)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struct is a ruby class, it created a Class object that contains attributes and accessors, you don't need define a class explicitly. In the api ,you can find more details : http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html.

In your case , it create a class that contains 2 attributes named "user" and "meeting", then class MeetingReminderJob inherits it.

Comment: Amazing, what a great language!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example:

```
class Animal
  def greet
    puts "Hi.  I'm an animal"
  end
end

def get_class
  return Animal
end

class Dog < get_class
  def warn
    puts "Woof."
  end
end

Dog.new.greet
Dog.new.warn

--output:--
Hi.  I'm an animal
Woof.
```

And another:

```
class Dog < Class.new { def greet; puts "Hi"; end }
  def warn
    puts "Woof."
  end
end

Dog.new.greet
Dog.new.warn


--output:--
Hi
Woof.
```